# Get last displayed item using ngFor at any instance in Angular 5

Tags: angular

I have an Object which I am using to display in my HTML using `*ngFor`. Now at any instance, I want to know the last displayed data.

Ex:-
I have an object as `totalItems`;

Now in HTML, I display it as:

```
<p *ngFor="let item of totalItems">

{{item.Name}}
```

What I want is `if item.Name` is same as last displayed `item.Name`, another thing will be printed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `last` in `ngFor` directive.

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of totalItems; let last = last">
    <p *ngIf="!last">{{item.Name}}</p>
    <p *ngIf="last">Another thing to display</p>
</ng-container>
```

Wrap your elements in container, so you can use both `ngFor` and `ngIf`.

There are also `index`, `first`, `even` and `odd`, you should read documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can do with *ngIf

```
< *ngFor="let item of totalItems; let last = last">
< *ngIf="item.Name == last.Name">
```